# Should I install nvidia drivers, even if I don't use it?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a laptop with dual GPU (Intel HD and Nvidia).

I disabled nvidia from `nvidia-settings`  and use Intel HD only all the time.

If I install fresh Ubuntu without nvidia drivers, does it mean that my nvidia GPU is already disabled ?

Is there a difference between (Install drivers then disable from `nvidia-settings`) and (Install fresh Ubuntu without drivers)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you don't use the Nvidia drivers, there is no need to install them, and the initial Ubuntu installs don't have them by default anyway.  After an uninstall, there might be some leftover configuration files which interfere with things (like login), but if you don't experience any problems, the  result is equivalent to a fresh install without the drivers.
  The reasons for using the Nvidia drivers:

1. You need to use the Nvidia hardware for a second monitor on some machines.
2. Nvidia drivers give you better performance on some high intensity graphics applications.
3. Nvidia drivers might run cooler than the nouveau for some high intensity graphics applications.
4. You get some additional control settings with the Nvndia-settings.

The nouveau drivers (on a laptop) may have the advantage of less screen tearing when scrolling. Also, if you need to be running secure boot, they are far easier to get running and don't need constant manual intervention (signing any kernel/grub/shim updates).

Use what you feel best fits your needs.